# How to check if string is in valid HTML format

Tags: jquery, html

My requirement is, on a web form if i select some strings, On click of a button i should be able to know if my selected string is in valid HTML syntax or not

```
 function chkhtml() {
            var code = $("<table><td>");
        code.each(function () {
           if($(this).html())
           {
            alert('success')
           } 
           else
           {
            alert('fail');
           }
        })
    }
```

Suppose i write the above code, it should alert me false but it alerts true

Comment: run it through validator.w3.org?

Comment: For a JS answer see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026626/check-if-html-snippet-is-valid-with-javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
var code = $("<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>");
code.each(function() {
    alert( $(this).html() ); //returns 1 if HTML 
})
```

I think this is the probable solution by using HTML and J-Query.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it juste gets the html of the element