# Reactjs dangerouslySetInnerHtml Alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, blogs

So I'm currently building a blogpost and the entire 'post' of this JSON file contains HTML in it, things like `<p></p>` or `<br>` and such. What's the most efficient way to place this in my ReactApp? I have no trouble getting everything else in but have no clue how to handle the 'post' part since different articles may have `<br>` and such in different areas and would like to avoid using dangerouslySetInnerHTML or at least find a safe way of using it.

Comment: Can you switch from HTML to Markdown?

Comment: @gcedo Markdown itself doesn't add any security unless you disable embedding HTML in it.

Comment: True, forgot to explicitly mention it.

Comment: Duplicate of: Looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to sanitize your HTML before inserting it in the DOM via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Hope it works!