# Alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, code-injection, tsx

I use React to build a web app that stores documents. Those are created in HTML and are then stored in a database. To show them in the app I load the HTML inside a `div` by making use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.page.content}} />
```

Even through this works perfectly fine, the name `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` suggests to pay more attention to this case, but I wonder what exactly can be done to remain flexible enough to load HTML and make it appear in the web app. I believe that the word *dangerous* addresses the danger of cross-site scripting, meaning that a script could be injected, executing harmful code.

As a countermeasure I thought of cleaning the HTML code before parsing it over to the `div`. One library addressing this is [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify). Another way would be to convert the HTML code from the database directly into React Elements using [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser).

Would that be the right approach? Or are there alternatives to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is called so to make sure that you know what you are doing. There is no safe way to achieve this without some cleaning of the HTML code unless you trust the code in the database.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps these parsers can fulfill ur need

[html-to-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react)

[html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser)