# Add className attribute to dangerouslySetInnerHTML contents

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

How to specify `className` attribute for `div` which contains 'hello world':

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<div>hello world</div>'}} />
```

One way is to set is to outer div like so:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<div>hello world</div>'}} className='class-name'/>
```

and then in css style the child:

```
.class-name div {
  (css stuff here)
}
```

But I want to set `className` directly to the `div` with 'hello world'

EDIT: Adding class name to injected html does not solve the problem, for example:

```
let content = '<div class="class-name">hello world</div>'
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}}
```

does not work, because in case same content is used many times then CSS collisions occur (I am using style-loader with CSS modules on)

Comment: As you updated your question, may you clarify if your class names are static or dynamic?

Comment: @lumio dynamic, for example CSS modules convert className into something like this: componentName_className__1eKtRuyKh

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question after 2 years and I wanted to achieve the exact same results. I didn't find any accurate answers here but I came up with a solution thanks to **[@jash8506](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15420394/jash8506)** due to the brilliant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278282/13833218) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53539885/13833218).

We have to utilize two react hooks

1. [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)
2. [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)

According to the documentation basically, `useRef` can be used to access the DOM elements in React and `useLayoutEffect` can be used to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render.

We can access the `firstChildElement` in the container `div` and add classes to it's `classList`

Here is how the completed code looks like

```
const containerRef = useRef();

useLayoutEffect(()=>{
  if (containerRef.current){
    containerRef.current.firstElementChild.classList.add('class-name');
  }
});

return (
  <div ref={elRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<div>hello world</div>'}} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="post-excerpt" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.excerpt}}/>
```