# Replace string inside the props

Tags: reactjs

The following component:

```
import React from 'react';

const container = ({ items }) => (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: items,
      }}
    />
);
export default container;
```

returns:

```
<div classname="myDiv"></div>
```

I'm trying to replace **classname** with **class**, but not sure how to do so.

I tried different ways for example this without any success:

```
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: items.replace('classname', 'class')
      }}
    />
```

How can I replace the string inside the props?

Comment: have you tried `replaceAll`? maybe you have multiple strings

Comment: is `items` a string? If you can somehow get the DOM object for the element it would be much easier.

Comment: Here is an answer to your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539885/how-to-pass-style-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-react/68278282#68278282)