# <br> read as string instead as it function of breaking a new line

Tags: reactjs

read as string in react js instead of its function

this the full code

render:

```
   var deskripsi = <p>{products.deskripsi}</p>;

return:
{deskripsi}
```

deskripsi data:

```
  BODY<br/>
    Dimensions : 156.9 x 75.8 x 7.8 mm (6.18 x 2.98 x 0.31 in)<br>
    Weight : 168 g (5.93 oz) <br/>
    Build : Front glass, plastic body <br/>
    SIM : Single SIM (Nano-SIM) or Dual SIM (Nano-SIM, dual stand-by) <br/>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is deskripsi a string? why not make it an object?

Comment: Your return shouldn’t have a colon.

Comment: If you want to render a string as HTML, gotta use this: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render a variable containing HTML tags, you could use the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` property: [documentation on reactjs.org - DOM Elements # dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Note this is, as said, dangerous. It's explained in the documentation rendering HTML from a variable could be a XSS vulnerability:

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

For more information, you should read articles on this topic. Here is an article to explain XSS attacks:

> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) is a vulnerability in web applications and also the name of a client side attack in which the attacker injects and runs a malicious script into a legitimate web page. Browsers are capable of displaying HTML and executing JavaScript.
>
> — Satyam Singh, Oct 4, 2018 - [5 Practical Scenarios for XSS Attacks - pentest-tools.com](https://pentest-tools.com/blog/xss-attacks-practical-scenarios/)

Using the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` property, your code should look like this:

```
var deskripsi = <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ __html: products.deskripsi }></p>;
```

Hope it'll help!

Comment: If you are aware of the vulnerability, some workarounds maybe exist. The topic is discussed in this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml