# React add HTML tags on string using predetermined components (alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I do not want to employ dangerouslySetInnerHTML and the objective here is to put bold tags around each instance of a word that appears in my string.

Convention React wisdom might suggest that something like this ***could*** work?

```
const Bold = (props) => {
   return (
      <b>
         {props.txt}
      </b>
   );
};
```

Here is where I try to incorporate the code

```
   if (longString.includes(searchTerm)) {
      longString = longString.replace(rest, <Bold txt={rest} />);
   }
```

> Problem is it comes out as **[object Object]** instead of desired **<b>searchTerm</b>**

How do I do set up the string swap so that it doesn't print the word [object] but rather prints the object?

Comment: jsx is not a string

Comment: I am aware of that

Comment: [Safe alternative to dangerouslySetinnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `renderToString` from `react-dom`

```js
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

if (longString.includes(searchTerm)) {
  longString = longString.replace(rest, renderToString(<Bold txt={rest} />) );
}
```