# Any security issue in using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render HTMLCode inside react.js sharepoint webpart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss, sharepoint-online, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am trying to build a React.Js SharePoint modern web part, which have the following capabilities:-

1. Inside the Web Part settings page >> there are 2 fields named as "Who We Are" & "Our Value" which allow the user to enter HTML.
2. The web part will render 2 buttons "Who We Are" & "Our Value" >> and when the user clicks on any button >> a Popup will be shown with the entered HTML code in step-1

Something as follow:-

[image]

But to be able to render HTML code as Rich-Text inside my Web Part, i have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute inside the .tsx file, as follow:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@fluentui/react-hooks';
import {
  getTheme,
  mergeStyleSets,
  FontWeights,
  Modal,
  IIconProps,
  IStackProps,
} from '@fluentui/react';
import { IconButton, IButtonStyles } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
export const MYModal2 = (myprops) => {
  const [isModalOpen, { setTrue: showModal, setFalse: hideModal }] = useBoolean(false);
  const [isPopup, setisPopup] = React.useState(true);
  const titleId = useId('title');
  React.useEffect(() => {
      showModal();
  }, [isPopup]);
  function ExitHandler() {
    hideModal();
    setisPopup(current => !current)
    myprops.handler();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        titleAriaId={titleId}
        isOpen={isModalOpen}
        onDismiss={ExitHandler}
        isBlocking={true}
        containerClassName={contentStyles.container}
      >
        <div className={contentStyles.header}>
          <span id={titleId}>Modal Popup</span>
          <IconButton
            styles={iconButtonStyles}
            iconProps={cancelIcon}
            ariaLabel="Close popup modal"
            onClick={ExitHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div  className={contentStyles.body}>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}>
   </p>

        </div>
      </Modal>

    </div>

  );
};

const cancelIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: 'Cancel' };

const theme = getTheme();
const contentStyles = mergeStyleSets({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column nowrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  header: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line deprecation/deprecation
    theme.fonts.xLarge,
    {
      flex: '1 1 auto',
      borderTop: '4px solid ${theme.palette.themePrimary}',
      color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      fontWeight: FontWeights.semibold,
      padding: '12px 12px 14px 24px',
    },
  ],
  body: {
    flex: '4 4 auto',
    padding: '0 24px 24px 24px',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    selectors: {
      p: { margin: '14px 0' },
      'p:first-child': { marginTop: 0 },
      'p:last-child': { marginBottom: 0 },
    },
  },
});
const stackProps: Partial<IStackProps> = {
  horizontal: true,
  tokens: { childrenGap: 40 },
  styles: { root: { marginBottom: 20 } },
};
const iconButtonStyles: Partial<IButtonStyles> = {
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralPrimary,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginTop: '4px',
    marginRight: '2px',
  },
  rootHovered: {
    color: theme.palette.neutralDark,
  },
};
```

so my question is; if using

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:myprops.OurValue}}></p>
```

can poses any security issues to render HTMLCode inside react.js sharepoint webpart? and if so can i eliminate this security issue? if not, then can i use a safer approach to render HTML code as Rich-Text inside a Popup?

Thanks

Here is my Full web part code:-

inside the MyModalPopupWebPart.ts:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'MyModalPopupWebPartStrings';
import MyModalPopup from './components/MyModalPopup';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './components/IMyModalPopupProps';

export interface IMyModalPopupWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  WhoWeAre: string;
  OurValue:string;
}

export default class MyModalPopupWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMyModalPopupWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> = React.createElement(
      MyModalPopup,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        WhoWeAre: this.properties.WhoWeAre,
        OurValue: this.properties.OurValue
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('WhoWeAre', {
                  label: "who We Are",
    multiline: true
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('OurValue', {
                  label: "Our value"
                }), PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: "Description",
    multiline: true
                }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

inside the MyModalPopup.tsx:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMyModalPopupProps } from './IMyModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IMyModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IMyModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMyModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes XSS if its user-supplied, if only you are using it then its fine and by design to allow arbitrary html/js. if it is user supplied/consumed/shared the fix is to create fields for *everything*, or a make a builder which asks for font, padding, margin, etc, etc then render to a set of predefined templates, think Wordpress page builder etc or use markdown in the input box then convert it to HTML on render, you could attempt to strip out all xss nastys but the code would become larger then your current codebase

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for you reply. when we create a SharePoint Web Part then any user can use it when creating or editing modern pages, we can not lock this down.. So seems doing so is not secure? is my conclusion correct? so my question now , is how i can secure my approach ? can you provide more details?

Comment: Why  i have one close request and it mentioned it needs more details... what other details i need to supply!!!

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @LawrenceCherone seems the link contains many approaches .. so which one i can use inside my SharePoint web part?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so what i did >> i install this inside my project `npm install dompurify eslint-plugin-risxss` >> then i added the following import to my `MyModal.tsx` `import { sanitize } from 'dompurify';` >> then i render the HTML using this code `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(myprops.WhoWeAre) }} />` .. so i am doing things correctly?