# How to render specific HTML tags from a text in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, regex

I have a dynamic text coming from my server with some HTML tags in it. I don't want to "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" because of security reasons and because I only want to allow specific html tags like `<i> <b> <strong> <em>`. I don't want to allow any other tag to be rendered like for example  or

So let's say I have the following string

```
This is a text with a <b>bold</b> tag and a <strong>strong</strong> tag. It also includes <i>italic</i> and <em>em</em> tags.
```

If I render this text I want to render it as followed in my HTML:

This is a text with a **bold** tag and a **strong** tag. It also includes *italic* and *em* tags.

Comment: If you know the injected HTML is safe, then go with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. See [Safe alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044518/safe-alternative-to-dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for details.

Comment: But i don't want to render <a> or <h1> tags etc, only the specific ones described above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the **dompurify** library and created a reusable component in React.

html-tag-renderer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const HTMLTagRenderer = ({ string, allowedTags }) => {
  const cleanHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(string, { ALLOWED_TAGS: allowedTags });

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: cleanHTML }} />;
};

HTMLTagRenderer.propTypes = {
  string: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  allowedTags: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default HTMLTagRenderer;
```

can be used like:

```
 <HTMLTagRenderer allowedTags={['b', 'em', 'strong', 'i']} string="This is a text with a <b>bold</b> tag and a <strong>strong</strong> tag. It also includes <i>italic</i> and <em>em</em> tags." />
```