# Regular expression HTML tag javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

I want to verify if the code that enter is a HTML code ( is necessary to start with `<html>` and end with `</html>` )

I try to do this

```js
var reghtml = new RegExp("(<html>*\n+</html>)");
```

but I have a problem is necessary to make a \n in the code, I need to verify the first and end tag ( = `<html>` and `</html>` ) and if he make something between them is necessary to start with `<` and end with `>`

is there any solution ?

Comment: Sorry, *and if he make something between them is necessary to start with `<` and end with `>`* is rather unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if he make like this `<html></html>` it's correct, but if he want to make something between the tag he need to start with `<` and end with `>`, for example `<html> test </html>` => error | `<html> <test> </html>` => correct

Comment: Something like `/^<html>(?:\s*<[^>]*>)*<\/html>$/.test(your_html)`?

Comment: Have you looked into validation without regular expressions? Regex and HTML don't mix very well

Comment: @Dbz, I want to check a code ( the user give it )

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it's work, but there's a small mistake, if I Back to line and I write a correct code it's give me **error**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there any solution ?

Comment: I do not understand *if I Back to line and I write a correct code it's give me error*. Please provide some valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I write like this `<html><test></html>` it's work correctly (this's what I want) but if I make like this `<html>` and I enter and write `<test>` and enter for second time `</html>` it's give me **error**

Comment: I [cannot repro](https://jsfiddle.net/h0r2tb1n/), please provide a js fiddle to show the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use regular-expressions to validate HTML (let alone parse it) because HTML is not a "[Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)".

So here's an example of a false-negative case which would cause any regular expression you could write to attempt to validate HTML to mark it as invalid:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- </html> -->
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is valid HTML</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And because you can nest comments in HTML (and SGML and XML) you can't write a straightforward regex for this particular case either:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <!-- <!-- <!-- </html> -->
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is valid HTML</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's a false-positive (assuming you don't use the `^$` regex anchors):

```
<p>illegal element</p>
<html>
    <img>illegal text node</img>
</html>
<p>another illegal element</p>
```

Granted, there are more powerful implementations of of regular-expressions that add rudiminary support for things like counting-depth, but then you're in for a world of hurt.

The correct way to validate HTML is to use a HTML DOM library. In .NET this is HtmlAgilityPack. In browser-based JavaScript it's even simpler: just use the browser's built-in parser (`innerHTML`):

(stolen from [Check if HTML snippet is valid with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026626/check-if-html-snippet-is-valid-with-javascript) )

```
function isValidHtml(html) {
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocuiment("");
    doc.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
    return ( doc.documentElement.innerHTML === html );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a pattern for you. It checks if the first level has a valid opening and closing tag. The first level has to have closing tags, you can't do `<html><img /></html>`, for that you can remove the whole closing tag checking pattern part.

```js
var validHtml = '\
<html itemscope>\
 <head></head>\
 <body style="background: red;">\
  Everything is fine\
 </body>\
</html>\
',
 invalidHtml = '\
<html itemscope>\
 <head></foot>\
 <body>\
  Nothing is fine\
 </body>\
</html>\
',
 pattern = /^\s*<html(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:\s*<(\w+)(?:\s[^>]+)?>(?:.|\s)*<\/\1>\s*)*<\/html>\s*$/i;
 
console.log(pattern.test(validHtml) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
console.log(pattern.test(invalidHtml) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
```