# Check if html valid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to check if html is valid. Basically I need to check in string whether  they closed or not. But I don't even know where to start.

Rules:

- It should return true if the string is valid, and false if it's invalid.
- All input strings will be nonempty, and will only consist of these html tags: .

Expected result

```
"<div></div>"   =>  True
"<div><span></span></div>"   =>  True
"<div></span>"       =>  False
"<div>"     =>  False
"<div><div><span></span></div></h1>" =>  False
```

So far I only have bare-bones. My Thoughts:

1. I tried to split all tag elements into different array. Using this [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters). But that answer didn't worked for me, and I can't select empty space because there is isn't any.
2. After splitting I would probably use for loops with if statement to compare this. Because it's only 3 tags I don't need anything fancy.

   ```
   const isHTMLValid = (html) => { 
   html = html.replace(/>/gi, ",>");
   html = html.split(',');
   console.log(html);

   }
   isHTMLValid("<div></div>");
   isHTMLValid("<div><span></span></div>");
   isHTMLValid("<div></span>");
   isHTMLValid("<div>");
   isHTMLValid("<div><div><span></span></div></h1>");
   ```

Comment: There is much more to valid HTML than just proper nesting. Is the nesting all you want to check?

Comment: The cool thing about browsers is that they have [a built-in HTML parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). Maybe use that?

Comment: Just to add to what @str said, consider the tag `<br />` - this is *valid* HTML but there is no nesting involved. And the tag `<br>` is equally valid.

Comment: Yes, i need only proper nesting.

Comment: [https://validator.w3.org/](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Yes, [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026626/check-if-html-snippet-is-valid-with-javascript) worked for me. I read it before just didn't think that it would work in this case. Expected to do something more difficult.