# How to gracefully handle react-dom error caused by dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: reactjs

The code below causes a react-dom error:

```
import React from "react";

const svg = `<svg><line x1=null y1="10" x2="100" y2="200" /></svg>`;

export default function App() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svg }} />;
}
```

> Error:  attribute x1: Expected length, "null".

How can I handle this error gracefully?

I expected that adding an error boundary would catch the problem, but it made no difference

```
import React from "react";

const svg = `<svg><line x1=null y1="10" x2="100" y2="200" /></svg>`;

let withErrorBoundary;
try {
  withErrorBoundary = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svg }} />;
} catch {
  <div>oops! content could not be rendered</div>;
}
export default function App() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svg }} />;
}
```

EDIT: Dump of error as requested by @DennisWash

[image: Dump of error]

Comment: Are you sure it gives an error? Try to replicate it https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-bik04?file=/index.js

Comment: Why exposing security breach, rather than [simply](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs) doing something, like `import {ReactComponent as MyLine} from './line.svg'`?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov: I haven't found anything that works for me yet, but I hope that I will. I tried rendering the SVG as a background (https://medium.com/@ians/rendering-svgs-as-images-directly-in-react-a26615c45770), but then the browser did not render the SVG at all if it encountered any syntax problem, in which case I prefer the behavior I have with injected SVG where the browser does a best effort to render the content. I have the SVG as a string (not a file) and don't use webpack, so am unsure how to achieve your suggestion. I will say that at least I sanitize the SVG before inserting.

Comment: @DennisVash I added a screen dump of the error to the question

Comment: You can use svg elements in JSX without having to dangerously set them by the way. Doing `<div><svg>...</svg></div>` will mostly work. This can also allow for IDE warnings when something is wrong with the elements

Comment: @apokryfos: The SVG string is created at runtime, so I can't use that option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if HTML snippet is valid with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026626/check-if-html-snippet-is-valid-with-javascript)

Comment: @apokryfos: That might be the best solution. I would prefer to be able to catch the error from react-dom. But maybe there isn't any mechanism for that.