# How to prevent a custom html content to mess with my page layout

Tags: html

I have an html page in which the user will be able to insert custom HTML content. For instance, it could be something like this:

```
<div class='main-container'>
   <div class='previous-stuff'>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class='custom-content'>
        {Custom content from user}
    </div>
    <div class='next-stuff'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I used `document.querySelector('custom-content').innerHtml = customContent` to set the content. If the custom content has a unclosed `div`, for instance, it will mess up with the rest of the page.

Is there any way to "shield" the rest of the page from problems from the custom content?

I don't think its relevant, but the page is a WordPress page.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript

Comment: I think you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216406/8583669. Also don't forget to **disable javascript's code** or user will be able to run javascript on your website