# Force a variable to be a valid HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-builder

In an Angular app, I am looking for a way to force a variable in TypeScript to be a valid HTML template, so that this will be compiled successfully:

```
let v = '<div>bla…</div>'
```

but this:

```
let v = '<cc></div>'
```

will cause a compilation error.

Is there such a possibility?

**Edited:**

If there is no way at compile time, maybe there is a way to make the Angular Cli Builder crash at build time in this case?

Comment: This seems to be attracting answers thinking you're looking to do a runtime check in JavaScript. Could you please [edit] to clarify that you're looking for the TypeScript type system to validate that a string [literal type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) is a valid HTML at compile time, and explicitly say what you mean by that ("valid" HTML isn't really an easily expressed thing; you might want to just match tags, which is recursive and still fairly difficult in TS, but I can at least *imagine* it, whereas full HTML validation is probably just "no")

Comment: If all you're trying to do is match tags, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjo5bN) is how I might begin to do it.  But, do you really want to go down such a route with nested conditional template literal types?  Let me know if you want to see this as an answer (and please [edit] to clarify what your goal is. Note that comments are ephemeral so anything you need people to know about the question should be an [edit] and not a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible to validate html strings at compile time.

Here is how to check validity of html at runtime [Check if HTML snippet is valid with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026626/check-if-html-snippet-is-valid-with-javascript)

Depending on your use case, you may also need to sanitize html or bypass sanitizer, using https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer